# issue with web scraper python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I started writing a webscraper in python using requests module in python when i send open website using this line of code

q=requests.post(url,data=payload)

payload i captured from burpsuite

> ctl00$OnlineContent$ScriptManager1=ctl00$OnlineContent$Updatepanel1|ctl00$OnlineContent$btnGetData&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKMTQ2ODcyMzU1Mw9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWBgIBDxYCHgNzcmMFF34vaW1hZ2VzL29ubGluZWxvZ28uanBnZAIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dAUoQS5QLlRyYW5zcG9ydCBEZXBhcnRtZW50IE9ubGluZSBTZXJ2aWNlc2RkAhUPZBYCAgUPZBYCZg9kFgICDQ9kFgICIw88KwANAGQYAQUbY3RsMDAkT25saW5lQ29udGVudCRndmRsc3VzD2dkOZ3fJwrMDniuOIr36W/pcIeY9Cs=&__PREVIOUSPAGE=kRa_y-H9KkgKR72aupDjyPGsQHMjHvvPoLZYv2z3H--ToWYU-XKGB_6SWaEFcaDLT52iED4axg4raKfE2TQnH0jFMPazeHbavbmWp-nnAnVyw0ReQW9KD-EXzTMpENJl6481bA2&ctl00$OnlineContent$ddlInput=R&ctl00$OnlineContent$txtInput=XXXXXXX&ctl00$OnlineContent$btnGetData=Get
> Data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm

print "contacting Server ....."
print "Fetching results...."
for i in tqdm(range(0,64)):
    url="https://aptransport.in/APCFSTONLINE/Reports/VehicleRegistrationSearch.aspx"
    payload={}
    q=requests.post(url,data=payload)
    idno += 1
    s=BeautifulSoup(q.text,'html.parser')
    htmlfile = open("gitamresults.html",'a')
    htmlfile.write(str(s))
    htmlfile.close()
```

what is the payload is have to give from the above request captured from burpsuite to python program

Comment: What are you trying to post to the page ?

Comment: in burpsuite request there is parameter XXXXXXXX that i want to post

Comment: Your payload should be a dictionary with input names as keys and input data as values, eg `payload={ 'ctl00$OnlineContent$txtInput' : 'XXXXXXX' , 'ctl00$OnlineContent$btnGetData' : 'Get Data', etc }` . Try to post all inputs in the page.

Comment: we have to give only inputs no need of _EVENTARGET and _EVENTARGUMENT etc  all these parameters??

Comment: I suggest you start with 'ctl00$OnlineContent$ddlInput', 'ctl00$OnlineContent$txtInput' and 'ctl00$OnlineContent$btnGetData' ,  and see how it goes . Propably you ll have to post all fields .